# MAIL attachments turn to zero kb

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, encryption

i have configured my Google APP email account on my new MACbook Pro (OS x 10.9.4).

it was working fine for couple of days but now any attachment that i try to save it get save with ZERO size.

**Note: this problem is only with Encrypted Folders.** 
if i download the save attachment to unencrypted folder, there is no problem encrypted

Comment: so you have the Google Apps Message Encryption (GAME) is an email encryption service for Google Apps customers, and need to set it up.

Answer (score 1):

Google APP email uses Google designed Encryption.

To set it up you need to use the [Google Apps Message Encryption Quick Start Guide.](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6105277?hl=en)

For the Attachment settings see the Google instructions  [Attachment compliance setting](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2364580?hl=en)

Basically what it means is you have to tell Google APP how to handle the attachments.

To configure Attachment compliance settings for your domain or organizational unit:

```
Sign in to the Google Admin console.
From the dashboard, go to Apps > Google Apps > Gmail > Advanced settings.
In the Organizations section, highlight your domain or the organizational unit for which you want to configure settings (see Configure advanced settings for Gmail for more details).
Scroll down to the Attachment compliance section:
    If the setting's status is Not configured yet, click Configure (the "Add setting" dialog box displays).
    If the setting's status is Locally applied, click Edit to edit an existing setting (the "Edit setting" dialog box displays), or click Add another to add a new setting (the "Add setting" dialog box displays).
    If the setting’s status is Inherited, click View to view the inherited setting, or click Add another to add a new setting (the "Add setting" dialog box displays).
When you're finished with your changes, click Add setting or Save to close the dialog box.
```

Comment: but how it was working at the first place. What Google App encryption setting have to do with my local hard drive.

Comment: the Google setting would make sure the attachments are forwarded as encrypted, which is not the case now, they come over as not encrypted, if i understood you right. The attachments are forwarded but not as part of encrypted email !

Comment: i am using encryption at rest. i have followed this link http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/encrypt-mac-folder/ to create encrypted folder. i am saving the attachment to this folder. there is no encryption used anywhere else.